# Difference between SqlDataReader, DataTable and DataSet and their uses

Tags: c#

I was going through an article related to SQL Server data access and came across three methods:

```
public SqlDataReader ExecuteReader(string procedureName, IDictionary<string, IConvertible> parameters = null) 

public DataTable ExecuteDataTable(string procedureName, IDictionary<string, IConvertible> parameters = null)  

public DataSet ExecuteDataSet(string procedureName, IDictionary<string, IConvertible> parameters = null)
```

These were the methods written in abstract `DataAccessBase` class.

Can someone please explain me, what is the need of returning `SqlDataReader`, `DataTable` and `DataSet`? Which scenarios we will be using those?

Comment: You have to read and try each one, start by msdn and do some tests yourself, you will understand exactly what they are, and there are many articles online going through them in details such as : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/difference-between-datareader-dataset-dataadapter-and-datatable-in-c-sharp1

Comment: There are ***tons*** of great, basic beginner's tutorials on ADO.NET which explain all of this in great details - just fire up your favorite search engine and start (re)searching!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataSet` and `DataTable` are related, a `DataSet` *can* contain multiple tables. Both are in-memory collections like a `List` or `Array`. But a `SqlDataReader` isn't related since it's a forward-only stream directly to the database. So it gives you access to exactly one data-record, [`reader.Read`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) will advance it to the next record.

You should read tutorials and documentation about ADO.NET and these classes. The first port of call is always MSDN. For example [`SqlDataReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx) or [DataSets, DataTables, and DataViews](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ss7fbaez(v=vs.110).aspx).